# How to push only if list is empty in one Redis transaction?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, list, redis

I am trying to make a small queue. I need to pop the first value in the queue/list otherwise push a new value. Can it be done in one transaction? I tried to use 2 requests: LPOP and send LPUSH.

If LPOP doesn't return anything. But It doesn't work, as MONITOR displays:

```
"lpop" "ns:queue"
"lpop" "ns:queue" 
"lpop" "ns:queue"

"rpush" "ns:queue" "1"
"rpush" "ns:queue" "2"
"rpush" "ns:queue" "3"
```

Async is doing it's business. At the end all 3 connections will be in the queue, instead of just one. I believe MULTI doesn't work with conditional statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use lua script for this, check redis documents for more info.

The below lua script calls lpop if result found return the element else it will push data using lpush. Hope this answers the question.

```
eval "local v = redis.call('lpop', KEYS[1]); if not v then return redis.call('lpush', KEYS[1], ARGV[1]); else return v; end;" 1 "ns:queue" 1
```

Comment: I guess there is no other way to do this without scripting. I am not too familiar with Lua, so I was trying to avoid it. Thank you for your example, it helps a lot.